# Android Auto - Change theme at runtime

Tags: android, android-theme, android-auto

My Android Auto app is a multi radio stations app.
So I would like to have a different theme each time I switch radio.
So that each radio has its own theme.

Do you know if it is possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Auto playback menu is standard, and designed to be limited to be consistent and predictable in order to minimize any driver distractions.

While only the color of the button can be customized to distinguish a brand to some degree, the icons and actions can also be customized.

This page on [Designing For Auto](https://developer.android.com/design/auto/index.html) has a bit more info as well.